# Plantilla variádica de formación multidimensional

Tags: c++, c++11, template

Supongamos una plantilla con un tipo y un número arbitrario de valores:

```
template <typename tipo, int ... valores>
class matriz
{
};
```

¿De qué manera debo declarar una variable interna para que los `valores` sean las dimensiones de una formación multidimensional?

He probado las siguientes sintaxis sin éxito:

`1`

```
tipo datos[valores ...]{};
```

> ```
> error: expected ']' before '...' token
> ```

`2`

```
tipo datos[valores, ...]{};
```

> ```
> error: expected ']' before ',' token
> ```

`3`

```
tipo datos[valores][...]{};
```

> ```
> error: expected primary-expression before '...' token
> ```

`4`

```
tipo datos[(valores, ...)]{};
```

> ```
> warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect
> ```

La anterior se despliega como una serie de valores separados por coma de manera que `datos` acaba siendo una formación de una dimensión con el último tamaño facilitado a la plantilla.

`5`

```
tipo datos[valores * ...]{};
```

La anterior consigue una formación del tamaño adecuado, pero de una sola dimensión.

---

¿Es posible conseguir que se declare `matriz<int, 3, 3, 3>::datos` como `int[3][3][3]`?

Comment: Aquí tienes una solución: [Variadic Templates Multidimensional Array Container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7058427/8663418). Aunque, sinceramente, ¡ no la entiendo ! :-O

Comment: Ahora [ya lo entiendes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/279548/2742) ¿A qué esperas para responder?.

Comment: Jejeje ... Que tenga aceptada la respuesta no quiere decir, ni mucho menos, que la entienda. Como se suele decir, `no eres tu, soy yo` :-)

Comment: Si aceptas la respuesta sin entenderla, deberías inmediatamente des-aceptar la respuesta y pedir explicaciones adicionales hasta que lo entiendas.

Comment: Se que es una buena y correcta respuesta, y mas viniendo de ti. El problema es que a mi me cuesta entender algunas cosas. Pero eso es mi problema, no de la respuesta :-)

Comment: Tu reflexión no invalida mi postura.

Comment: ¡ Que no la voy a des-aceptar, *carajo* ! :-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias a la [pista](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7058427/8663418) compartida por [Trauma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/279333/plantilla-vari%c3%a1dica-de-formaci%c3%b3n-multidimensional#comment513893_279333) he podido ver que mi aproximación al problema era totalmente errónea.

---

#### Problema.

Uno de los componentes de las plantillas variádicas es el paquete de parámetros, que tiene el formato siguiente: `definición ... nombre`, por ejemplo:

```
template <typename ... tipos>
//        ~~~~~~~~     ~~~~~ <--- el paquete de parámetros se llama 'tipos'
//           ^
//            \__ una colección de tipos
```

```
template <int ... valores>
//        ~~~     ~~~~~~~ <--- el paquete de valores se llama 'valores'
//         ^
//          \__ una colección de 'int'
```

Los paquetes de parámetros se pueden desplegar de diferentes maneras, usando el nombre del paquete:

```
void f(tipos ...); // despliega el paquete en la forma f(tipo1, tipo2, tipo3, tipon);
void f<valores ...>(); // despliega el paquete en la forma f(valor1, valor2, valorn);
```

O con la sintaxis: `expresión(nombre)...`, por ejemplo:

```
función(tipos)... // despliega el paquete en la forma función(tipo1), función(tipo2), función(tipon)
```

En todos los casos el nombre del paquete, seguido de la elipsis (`...`) provocará el despliegue del paquete de parámetros, pero este despliegue no puede tener una forma diferente a las mencionadas, así que en esta declaración:

```
template <typename tipo, int ... valores>
class matriz
{
    tipo datos[valores]...;
};
```

La línea `tipo datos[valores]...;` no tiene la sintaxis adecuada para ser considerada un paquete de parámetros a desplegar.

#### Solución.

No se puede declarar una formación multidimensional mediante el despliegue de paquetes de parámetros, así que la única solución es crear el tipo de la formación de manera recursiva mediante tipos anidados, empezaremos con la plantilla que contendrá el tipo anidado:

```
// Formación de X Dimensiones.
template <typename tipo, unsigned ... dimensiones>
struct FormacionXD;
```

Esta plantilla acepta un tipo `tipo` e internamente publicará un tipo de la misma plantilla con una de las dimensiones menos, para conseguir esto necesitamos dos especializaciones:

1. Una especialización para cuando sólo quede una dimensión en el paquete de parámetros.

   ```
   // Formación de X Dimensiones, especialización con una sola dimensión.
   template <typename tipo, unsigned dimension>
   struct FormacionXD<tipo, dimension>
   {
       using matriz = tipo[dimension];
   }
   ```
2. Otra especialización que extraiga una de las dimensiones de `dimensiones`.

   ```
   /* Formación de X Dimensiones, especialización para acceder
      a una de las dimensiones y anidar internamente el resto. */
   template <typename tipo, unsigned dimension, unsigned ... dimensiones>
   struct FormacionXD<tipo, dimension, dimensiones ...>
   {
       using matriz = FormacionXD<tipo, dimensiones ...>::matriz[dimension];
   }
   ```

Por lo tanto, con `FormacionXD` podemos declarar `matriz` de la siguiente manera:

```
template <typename tipo, int ... valores>
class matriz
{
    using datos_t = typename FormacionXD<tipo, valores ...>::matriz;
    datos_t datos{};
};
```

¿Qué pasa cuando instanciamos con los parámetros `<int, 3, 4, 5>`?:

1. Hay dos plantillas candidatas:

   ```
   // (Candidata 1)
   template <typename tipo, unsigned ... dimensiones>
   struct FormacionXD;
   // (Candidata 2)
   template <typename tipo, unsigned dimension, unsigned ... dimensiones>
   struct FormacionXD<tipo, dimension, dimensiones ...> { ... };
   ```

   Siempre se escoge la más especializada, por lo tanto será la Candidata 2 la que se instanciará:

   ```
   struct FormacionXD
   {
       using matriz = FormacionXD<int, 4, 5>::matriz[3];
   };
   ```

   Esta instancia intenta instanciar de nuevo `FormacionXD`:
2. Instanciando `FormacionXD<int, 4, 5>` tenemos las mismas plantillas candidatas que en el punto anterior y la más especializada sigue siendo la Candidata 2:

   ```
   struct FormacionXD
   {
       using matriz = FormacionXD<int, 5>::matriz[4];
   };
   ```
3. La instanciación `FormacionXD<int, 5>` tiene de nuevo dos candidatas:

   ```
   // (Candidata 1)
   template <typename tipo, unsigned ... dimensiones>
   struct FormacionXD;
   // (Candidata 2)
   template <typename tipo, unsigned dimension>
   struct FormacionXD<tipo, dimension> { ... };
   ```

   Y una vez más la más especializada es la Candidata 2 que instanciada tendrá este aspecto:

   ```
   struct FormacionXD
   {
       using matriz = int[5];
   };
   ```

En resumen, `FormacionXD<int, 3, 4, 5>::matriz` es una formación de 3 `FormacionXD<int, 4, 5>::matriz` que a su vez es una formación de 4 `FormacionXD<int, 5>::matriz` que a su vez es una formación de 5 `int`.

Es un poco confuso pero al desenroscar todas las instancias tenemos:

- Una formación de tres...
- ... formación de cuatro...
- ... formación de cinco `int`.

Es decir: `int[3][4][5]`.

Comment: `Es un poco confuso ...` no es exactamente la expresión que yo usaría :-O

Comment: ¿Qué cambiarías de la respuesta para que fuese menos "*un poco confuso*"?

Comment: Nada nada, ni una coma. Entiendo perfectamente la idea detrás, la sustitución recursiva. Simplemente, que este tipo de meta-programación me resulta muy muy difícil de asimilar. Meter un cuadrado por un *bujerito* redondo :-)