# Interpretación de plantillas

Tags: c++, c++11, template

Conozco varios tipo de plantillas:

- Predeclaración:

  ```
  template< typename T1, typename T2, typename T3 > MyTemplate;
  ```
- Forma *clásica* o *simple*:

  ```
  template< typename T1, typename T2, typename T3 > MyTemplate{
    ...
  };
  ```
- Especialización parcial (con uno o varios parámetros de plantilla reemplazados por tipos reales):

  ```
  template< typename T1, typename T2 > MyTemplate< T1, T2, bool > {
    ...
  };
  ```
- Por último, la especialización completa (todos los parámetros de plantilla han sido reemplazos por tipos reales):

  ```
  template< > MyTemplate< int, int, char * > {
    ...
  };
  ```

Recientemente me he topado con esto:

```
template< class T, unsigned ... RestD > struct array;

template< class T, unsigned PrimaryD > struct array< T, PrimaryD > {
  typedef T type[PrimaryD];
  type data;
};

template< class T, unsigned PrimaryD, unsigned ... RestD > struct array< T, PrimaryD, RestD... > {
  typedef typename array< T, RestD... >::type OneDimensionDownArrayT;
  typedef OneDimensionDownArrayT type[PrimaryD];
  type data;
};
```

No consigo entenderlo. Es una especie de ... ¿ especialización ? ¿ Con parámetros en lugar de tipos ?

<sub>Si es demasiado amplia, se admiten sugerencias para acotarla y dejarla *aceptable*.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero es la declaración `array` (decirle al compilador que existe, pero sin entrar en detalles).

```
// Plantilla 'array' con un tipo T seguido de número indeterminado de enteros sin signo.
template< class T, unsigned ... RestD > struct array;
```

Lo segundo es una especialización (decirle al compilador que quieres proponer una forma alternativa de algo que existe).

```
// Especialización de 'array' con tipo T y EXACTAMENTE un entero sin signo.
template< class T, unsigned PrimaryD > struct array { … };
```

Lo tercero es OTRA especialización.

```
/* Especialización de 'array' con tipo T y EXACTAMENTE un entero sin signo
   seguido de número indeterminado de enteros sin signo. */
template< class T, unsigned PrimaryD, unsigned ... RestD > struct array { … };
```

Es una práctica habitual para "*romper*" recursividad en plantillas variádicas.

---

La práctica mencionada se ve un poco más claramente con funciones que con objetos:

```
template <typename ... tipos>
int suma(tipos ... valores)
{
    // ???
}
```

Dado que la función anterior tiene todos los parámetros anónimos<sup>1</sup>, no hay manera de operar sobre ellos, ésta sería la función que declararíamos (sin definir):

```
template <typename ... tipos>
int suma(tipos ...);
```

Para poder operar sobre alguno de los parámetros, necesitamos especializar la plantilla para dar nombre a al menos uno de los parámetros:

```
template <typename T, typename ... tipos>
int suma(T cabeza, tipos ... cola)
{
    return cabeza + suma(cola ...);
}
```

Pero con las funciones declaradas no existe forma de romper la recursión, ya que la primera no está definida y la segunda se llama a si misma, debemos especializar el caso especial de UN parámetro para romper la recursión:

```
template <typename T>
T suma(T valor) { return valor; }
```

Así pues, para la llamada `auto x = suma(1, 2, 3);` el compilador haría las siguientes reflexiones:

1. Existe una declaración de `suma` con parámetros variádicos, pero la especialización de un parámetro fijado y el resto variádicos está definida y al estar más especializada es mejor opción, la instancia:

   ```
   suma(cabeza, cola_0, cola_1)
   {
       return cabeza + suma(cola_0, cola_1);
   }
   ```
2. Mismo caso que antes, la instancia:

   ```
   suma(cabeza, cola_0)
   {
       return cabeza + suma(cola_0);
   }
   ```
3. Existe una declaración de `suma` con parámetros variádicos, pero la especialización de un sólo parámetro está más especializada y es mejor opción:

   ```
   suma(valor)
   {
       return valor;
   }
   ```

---

Si aplicamos este conocimiento al objeto plantilla `array` con la definición `array<int, 3, 4, 5>` ¿Qué sucede?:

1. Existe una declaración de `array` con parámetros variádicos, pero la especialización de un parámetro fijado y el resto variádicos está definida y al estar más especializada es mejor opción, la instancia:

   ```
   template< int, 3, 4, 5 > struct array< int, 3, 4, 5 > {
     typedef typename array< int, 4, 5 >::type OneDimensionDownArrayT;
     typedef OneDimensionDownArrayT type[3];
     type data;
   };
   ```
2. Mismo caso que antes, la instancia:

   ```
   template< int, 4, 5 > struct array< int, 4, 5 > {
     typedef typename array< int, 5 >::type OneDimensionDownArrayT;
     typedef OneDimensionDownArrayT type[4];
     type data;
   };
   ```
3. Existe una declaración de `array` con parámetros variádicos, pero la especialización de un sólo parámetro está más especializada y es mejor opción:

   ```
   template< int, 5 > struct array< int, 5 > {
     typedef int type[5];
     type data;
   };
   ```

---

1. El paquete `valores` tiene nombre, pero los argumentos individuales no.

Comment: Gracias @Papper, pero has obviado algo que es lo que no entiendo. En el segundo caso, `template< class T, unsigned PrimaryD > struct array< T, PrimaryD > { ...` ¿ Porqué la especialización son también parámetros de plantilla ? El segundo conjunto de `< ... >`.

Comment: La especialización de plantilla contiene parámetros plantilla porque en caso contrario no sería una especialización de una plantilla.

Comment: No me explico. Tiene el mismo número de parametros en ambos conjuntos. En la especialización que yo conozco, las especializaciones tienen mas parámetros en el conjunto de la derecha, la ... *especialización*.

Comment: No, en ninguno de los casos tiene el mismo número de parámetros. En la declaración tiene 1 parámetro tipo (`T`) y X parámetros variádicos (0 >= X < ∞), en la primera especialización tiene 1 parámetro tipo (`T`) y un parámetro no-tipo, en la segunda especialización tiene 1 parámetro tipo, un parámetro no-tipo e Y parámetros variádicos (0 >= Y < ∞).

Comment: Ah, vale. Ok. Me queda grande este nivel de complejidad en las plantillas :-(